# Generate a video from an image url with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to generate a few seconds of video using a single image.
I tried `loop` argument:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 4.5 -i https://url/to/image.jpg ...
```

It works but seems like ffmpeg requests the url for each frame. The default `framerate` is 25, so it makes 100 requests for 4 seconds of video.

I can't set the `framerate` to 1 because I add a text animation, so frames should be changed frequently.

But even if I can I don't want to request the same image for each second.

As a workaround, I can firstly download the image and then use a local version. This way the video generating will be much faster.

But anyway, is it possible to force ffmpeg to cache that image somehow and use it for each frame?

Comment: You can probably create a script using wget or similar software to pull the image to a temporary local folder and then insert that into ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [loop](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loop) and [trim](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim) filters instead.

```
ffmpeg -i https://url/to/image.jpg -vf "loop=-1:1:0,trim=duration=4.5"  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. Just for my understanding (I'm new to ffmpeg): filters work with the once-received source (and ignore say changed image); if the source is being changed I need to do something near the source (near the `-i`) - in this case, the source will be re-requested, right?

Comment: If you want to keep reloading an image input, then you need `-stream_loop -1` before the input. If you do that, remove the filters in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i https://helloparent7222....  output.mp4
```

I use this command to generate a video, but a corrupted video is produced.